# Facebook Audience Network issues

Tags: facebook-ads-api, facebook-audience-network

We are currently using Facebook Audience Network with AdMob mediation on our iOS app. We are using latest version for FAN(5.2.0) and Google Ads(7.41.0) from CocoaPods. The implementation is done fully done as per the documentation here - https://developers.google.com/admob/ios/mediation/facebook  and tested the implementation using tools here - https://developers.facebook.com/docs/audience-network/testing however no error was found.

The issues are facing are that
1) The ad icon image is not being sent by Facebook to AdMob, we checked using direct Facebook Native ads and icons are present there but the same ad data shows icon as 'nil' when passed through mediation
2) We are seeing gray ad choices icons(as attached) however upon clicking the icon the app crashes with stack trace in FB library(stack trace attached).

[image]
[image]

Can any once advise on how we can get rid of these issues?

Answer (score 0):

Just set adOptionsView.nativeAd = nativeAd